# Mysql - Ordernar antes de agrupar

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by, distinct

Preciso fazer uma seleção que traga os últimos usuários que logaram, sem repetir os nomes. O problema é que o comando abaixo primeiro agrupa e depois ordena:

```
SELECT usuario FROM tab_logins GROUP BY usuario ORDER BY data_login  desc
```

Exemplo de tabela:

```
usuario, data_login
joão,    2018-01-01
maria,   2018-01-02
jose,    2018-01-03
joão,    2018-01-04
antonio, 2018-01-05
joão,    2018-01-06
```

Usando o comando que mencionei. Primeiro vai agrupar os nomes, e depois vai ordenar, trazendo um resultado errado:

```
antonio
jose
maria
joao
```

Sendo que o resultado correto, seria esse:

```
joão
antonio
jose
maria
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem como resolver isso da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT usuario
FROM tab_logins 
GROUP BY usuario 
ORDER BY MAX(data_login) desc;
```

A única diferença é a aplicação da função [MAX()](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-date.php)

Comment: Perfeito, @maxfratane!
Funcionou perfeitamente.
Obrigado